# JBoss AS 7 : how to make independant deployment of EJB and dependent WAR?

Tags: java, ejb, classpath, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x

I have an application with one EJB (`mwf_ejb.jar`) and a WAR (`mwf_web.war`). If I package them in the same EAR, everything is OK. Is there any way to deploy the EJB first, then the WAR ?

If I try it, my EJB JAR deploys well, but when I deploy my WAR, I get the following error (in JBoss AS 7.1.1):

```
MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."mwf_web.war".STRUCTURE:           org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."mwf_web.war".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "mwf_web.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given parent is not an ancestor of this virtual file
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:116)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:110)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestClassPathProcessor.createAdditionalModule(ManifestClassPathProcessor.java:193) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestClassPathProcessor.handlingExistingClassPathEntry(ManifestClassPathProcessor.java:185) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestClassPathProcessor.deploy(ManifestClassPathProcessor.java:160) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, I've added a "Class-Path" statement, to define dependency in the standard way:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.apache.log4j
Class-Path: mwf_ejb.jar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finaly manage to make it work, with this **MANIFEST.MF** file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.apache.log4j, deployment.mwf_ejb.jar
```

Plus adding, a lookup attribute in my **@EJB** annotations (which were originaly blank: @EJB):

```
@EJB(lookup="java:global/mwf_ejb/UserManager")
```

However, I think `deployment.` prefix is ok for JBoss, but not for other application servers.